# I think I have a problem with 'style.display' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have a small problem.
I want a button that shares more content.
So I need hiding content that when clicked show more and reverse also the function by hiding.

The problem is no matter what I do, the content inside id=more is always displayed.

I want is not displayed at the beginning.

I tried this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">More</button>
<div class="black" id="more">
    <p>I was supercool guys.... bla bla bla bla</p>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById('more');
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

And I tried this and there weren't any differences:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">More</button>
<div class="black" id="more">
    <p>I was supercool guys.... bla bla bla bla</p>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById('more');
  if (x.style.display == "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```

So what am I missing?

I am using HTML, JavaScript, and [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP).

Comment: The code works fine; if you can't see the result, it might be because the script tag isn't being ran; it might be because of JS being turned off in your browser, or having the script in the head tag or just simply having mistyped the some tags in the original file

Comment: I want that at the beginning the content insire the div ID=more is hiding... but is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works perfectly fine. Check out the following snippet.

```css
#more {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">More</button>
<div class="black" id="more">
  <p>I was supercool guys.... bla bla bla bla</p>
</div>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('more');
    if (x.style.display !== "block") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: If you run... i can see I was supercool... i want at beginning is hiding

Comment: I want the content inside id+more is hiding at beginning

Comment: Checkout the updated answer

Comment: Ok so i need to use the  "is not" !== thank you very much

Comment: Accept and upvote is a way to thanks here! :)

Comment: ah ok I did it! Thanks again